# Object Orientated Rust (The rust book chapter 17 blog)

Tags: rust

I want to implement the last bullet point on the [options of going further for creating the blog from *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-03-oo-design-patterns.html#trade-offs-of-the-state-pattern):

> Allow users to add text content only when a post is in the `Draft` state. Hint: have the state object responsible for what might change about the content but not responsible for modifying the `Post`.

I want to implement the `add_text` method that would have a default implementation that does nothing in the `State` trait but would push the string into `post.content` if the state was `Draft`:

```
pub struct Post {
    state: Option<Box<dyn State>>,
    content: String,
}

impl Post {
    pub fn new() -> Post {
        Post {
            state: Some(Box::new(Draft {})),
            content: String::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn add_text(&mut self, string: &str) {
        self.state.as_ref().unwrap().add_text(&mut self, string)
    }

    pub fn content(&self) -> &str {
        self.state.as_ref().unwrap().content(&self)
    }
}

trait State {
    fn content<'a>(&self, post: &'a Post) -> &'a str {
        ""
    }
    fn add_text<'a>(&self, post: &'a mut Post, string: &str) {
        "";
    }
}

impl State for Draft {
    fn add_text<'a>(&self, post: &'a mut Post, string: &str) {
        &mut post.content.push_str(string);
    }
}
```

My issue is around this line of `Post::add_text`

```
self.state.as_ref().unwrap().add_text(&mut self, string)
```

I get a cannot borrow as mutable try removing &mut.

However:

```
self.state.as_ref().unwrap().add_text(self, string)
```

Gives me 'cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable'.

Can someone help me with this? I am not sure whether I am going about this in the right way.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important.

Comment: Awesome - I will check out those tools next time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `state` is a member of `Post`. If you borrow `state` then you cannot mutably borrow `self` (that is the `Post`) at the same time, and that is right. Consider what would happen if your `Draft::add_text()` function were to assign to the received `post.state`:

```
impl State for Draft {
    fn add_text<'a>(&self, post: &'a mut Post, string: &str) {
        post.state = None; //killed self!
    }
}
```

That would make `self` disappear while this function is running! That would be terribly unsafe.

This usage pattern is not allowed in Rust, but you have several workarounds available. The nicest, IMO, would be to separate the data to be mutated into another type:

```
pub struct PostData {
    content: String,
}
pub struct Post {
    state: Option<Box<dyn State>>,
    data: PostData,
}
trait State {
    fn add_text<'a>(&self, post: &'a mut PostData, string: &str) {
        "";
    }
    //...
}
impl Post {
    pub fn add_text(&mut self, string: &str) {
        self.state.as_ref().unwrap().add_text(&mut self.data, string)
    }
}
```

This works because you are borrowing separated pieces of `self`, that is `self.state` on one hand and `self.data` on the other.

Another easy workaround would be to remove the status from the `Post` and re-add it later:

```
impl Post {
    pub fn add_text(&mut self, string: &str) {
        let state = self.state.take();
        state.as_ref().unwrap().add_text(&mut self, string);
        assert!(self.state.is_none());
        self.state = Some(state);
    }
}
```

Personally, I find this solution a bit *hacky*.

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution provided [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/book/issues/1079#issuecomment-369972431)

But this solution has a few deprecation warnings. [Here's my version which fixes the warnings](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=64f8cdbe0364da42c23e808b627a09c4)

For posterity's sake, here is the code in the provided playground link:

```
pub struct Post {
    state: Option<Box<dyn State>>,
    content: String,
}

impl Post {
    pub fn new() -> Post {
        Post {
            state: Some(Box::new(Draft {})),
            content: String::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn add_text(&mut self, text: &str) {
        self.content = self.state.as_ref().unwrap().add_text(&self.content, text);
    }

    pub fn content(&self) -> &str {
        self.state.as_ref().unwrap().content(&self)
    }

    pub fn request_review(&mut self) {
        if let Some(s) = self.state.take() {
            self.state = Some(s.request_review())
        }
    }

    pub fn approve(&mut self) {
        if let Some(s) = self.state.take() {
            self.state = Some(s.approve())
        }
    }
}

trait State {
    fn request_review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State>;
    fn approve(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State>;

    fn content<'a>(&self, _post: &'a Post) -> &'a str {
        ""
    }

    fn add_text(&self, original_text: &str, _text_to_add: &str) -> String {
        original_text.to_string()
    }
}

struct Draft {}

impl State for Draft {
    fn request_review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        Box::new(PendingReview {})
    }

    fn approve(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        self
    }

    fn add_text(&self, original_text: &str, text_to_add: &str) -> String {
        format!("{}{}", original_text, text_to_add)
    }
}

struct PendingReview {}

impl State for PendingReview {
    fn request_review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        self
    }

    fn approve(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        Box::new(Published {})
    }
}

struct Published {}

impl State for Published {
    fn request_review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        self
    }

    fn approve(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        self
    }

    fn content<'a>(&self, post: &'a Post) -> &'a str {
        &post.content
    }
}


fn main() {
    let mut post = Post::new();

    post.add_text("I ate a salad for lunch today");
    post.add_text("\nAnd a steak!");
    assert_eq!("", post.content());

    post.request_review();
    post.add_text("\nAnd dessert!");
    assert_eq!("", post.content());

    post.approve();
    post.add_text("\nAnd coffee!");
    assert_eq!("I ate a salad for lunch today\nAnd a steak!", post.content());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take.

Since it was hinted that the state will be responsible of what might change and not for modifying the Post, add add_text (or a much more appropriate function name) to the State trait. Make it accept a string slice.

```
trait State {
    // Some codes here
    fn add_text<'a>(&self, _text: &'a str) -> &'a str {
        ""
    }
}
```

Implement the add_text method for the Draft struct:

```
impl State for Draft {
    // Some codes here
    fn add_text<'a>(&self, text: &'a str) -> &'a str {
        text
    }
}
```

Re-write the add_text of Post struct in such a way that it will call add_text of the state and return the "change" that should be added to the current content.

```
impl Post {
    // Some codes here
    pub fn add_text(&mut self, text: &str) {
        if let Some(s) = self.state.as_ref() {
            let text = s.add_text(text);
            self.content.push_str(text)
        }
    }
    // Some codes here
}
```

Only Draft state will return the string slice we pass to it. We'll use the add_text of the state to determine what to append to the current content.

```
fn main() {
    let mut post = Post::new();

    post.add_text("I ate a salad for lunch today");
    post.add_text("\nThen slept");
    assert_eq!("", post.content());

    post.request_review();
    post.add_text("\nThen woke up");
    assert_eq!("", post.content());

    post.approve();
    post.add_text("\nThen got back to work");
    assert_eq!("I ate a salad for lunch today\nThen slept", post.content());
}
```